# Dimension of Representation of Majorana Fermions with Euclidean Metric?

Tags: representation-theory, spacetime-dimensions, dirac-matrices, majorana-fermions, clifford-algebra

It is possible to represent the Dirac matrices in the Majorana basis using $N= 2^{⌊d/2⌋}$-dimensional matrices, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices). This source uses a Minkowski metric. It would then be possible to move to a Euclidean metric by multiplying the time-like matrix by $i$, but then we aren't using the Majorana basis anymore. So is there a way to represent the matrices in the Majorana basis in $N= 2^{⌊d/2⌋}$ dimensions, or must we use $N= 2^{⌊(d+1)/2⌋}$?